# Variavel não atribuida em c#

Tags: c#

A variável no ultimo console.writeLine esta dando que não foi atribuída sendo que foi nos ifs, gostaria de saber o porque.

```
string c, nome;
double s, sn;

Console.WriteLine("Escreva o nome:");
nome = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Escreva o salário:");
s = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Escreva a categoria:");
c = Console.ReadLine();

if (c == "a" || c == "c" || c == "f" || c == "h")
{
    sn = s * 1.10;
}
else if (c == "b" || c == "d" || c == "e" || c == "i" || c == "j" || c == "t")
{
    sn = s * 1.15;
}
else if (c == "k" || c == "r")
{
    sn = s * 1.25;
}
else if (c == "l" || c == "m" || c == "n" || c == "o" || c == "p" || c == "q" || c == "s")
{
    sn = s * 1.35;
}
else if (c == "u" || c == "v" || c == "x" || c == "y" || c == "w" || c == "z")
{
    sn = s * 1.50;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Categoria inválida!");
}

Console.WriteLine(" Nome: {0}\n Categoria: {1}\n Novo salário: R$ {2:0.00}", nome, c, sn);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: A resposta foi postada pelo LINQ, mas você marcou o comentário do Pagotti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque, se o código cair no `else` a variável nunca receberá um valor.

Apenas inicialize a variável com o valor padrão.

```
double s, sn = 0;
// ...
```

Tentando ler o código, me parece que seria mais razoável "cancelar" a operação e retornar no `else`.

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Categoria inválida!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, vou mudar isso.Como ainda estou aprendendo não sei muito, então se quiser me passar as coisas que você falou que precisa mudar no código pra ver como posso melhorar.

Comment: Vou tirar isso pra não me comprometer por enquanto. Btw, se a resposta lhe foi útil você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **✓** no lado esquerdo da publicação. E você sempre pode votar positivamente nas publicações que achar interessante.

Comment: Gostaria de sugerir, caso esteja utilizando o Visual Studio, a utilizar breakpoints. Dessa forma, você consegue ver o caminho que seu código percorre.

Comment: @BrunoSoares seria melhor comentar na pergunta pra AP ser notificada. Postando na minha resposta somente eu recebo notificação.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação. Sou novo na plataforma e passou batido.

Answer (score 1):

> gostaria de saber o porque

Respondendo a sua pergunta, o motivo pelo qual ocorre essa mensagem, é que existe um caminho que o código pode percorrer, que é o último `else`, em que a variável `sn` não terá sido atribuída a nenhum valor e ao final do programa você está mostrando o valor dessa variável.

A solução que o @LINQ te passou para não ocorrer o erro é iniciar a variável com o valor 0 no começo. Outra forma seria colocar no último `else` uma instrução `sn = 0;`

Comment: A sua resposta é na verdade um comentário sobre a proposta que o LINQ já havia postado

Comment: Quando o @LINQ respondeu a primeira vez, ele respondeu como resolver o problema,  mas não tinha explicado porque ocorria a mensagem. A ideia da minha resposta era complementar a dele porque ele já tinha dado a solução e a pessoa que perguntou já tinha agradecido. Ele editou a resposta depois e incluiu a explicação, mas não sei porque a pessoa que fez a pergunta escolheu a minha resposta ao invés da dele.